# Combine Julia Dataframes by reference, instead of making copy

Tags: pointers, dataframe, julia

In Julia you can combine dataframes:

```
d1 = DataFrame(A=1:10)
d2 = DataFrame(A=11:20)

d3 = [d1; d2]
```

However this appears to copy d1, d2 into d3. I don't want to copy them. If you make a modification to d1, it is not reflected in d3.

Anyone know how to combine them by reference instead of by value, so that if d1 is modified, the change reflects in d3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Array type terminology, what you want is `d1` and `d2` to be views to the data in `d3`. This is also possible with DataFrames:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> d3 = DataFrame(A=1:20);

julia> d1 = view(d3,1:10);

julia> d2 = view(d3,11:20);

julia> d1[1:3,:]
3×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ A │
├─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 2 │
│ 3   │ 3 │

julia> d3[1:3,:]
3×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ A │
├─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 2 │
│ 3   │ 3 │

julia> d1[1,:A] = 999
999

julia> d3[1:3,:]
3×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ A   │
├─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 999 │
│ 2   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 3   │
```

Of course, you may want to create `d1` and `d2` first, and then combine them to `d3`, but this would require a copy operation (to make the columns contiguous in memory). After that, you can generate the views (and assign them to `d1` and `d2`). Using different variables for the views might be recommended as changing the type of `d1` and `d2` might cause type-instability (bad in Julia).

Comment: For arrays there's the CatViews.jl package that does what the OP wants, but it doesn't seem to work for DataFrames

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but it would work with a major refactor to my code, so i'll accept this answer.